# Excel Formula (if, sumproduct...)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this table in Excel where you can see the kg and the Price which I buy a product.

[image]

And I want to obtain the mean Price and the mean kg that I buy for each day of the week of January.
For the Kg:

```
=AVERAGEIF($B$4:$B$11;"Friday";D$4:D$11)
```

But I don't know how to do this for the mean of the Price because I have to consider the kg that I have bought. I have tried with *SumProduct, If, or Sumif*, but I can't do it.

I know how to do it if I add a new column that makes C*D but I prefer do it without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUM(IF(B4:B14="Friday",C4:C14*D4:D14))/SUM(IF(B4:B14="Friday",D4:D14))
```

> **IMPORTANT:** this is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: When I do that the result is 750, and i want to obtain (in this case) 50, because (50*10+50*20)/(10+20)

Comment: @user4563174 Sorry. I misread the question. I have updated my answer. Does this work?

Comment: Thank you! It Works! I will look this kind of array Formulas because it seems very usefull!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C4:C11,D4:D11*(B4:B11="Friday")) / CountIf(B4:B11,"Friday")
```